# How to integrate GWT-RPC, Android and GAE?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-syncproxy

I want to build a AppEngine GWT RPC app connected with an Android project with the RPC calls enabled between the server, GWT interface and the Android device. I know that is possible, but I still couldn't figure out how to do it. Can anyone explain to me how to do it? And maybe provide an example?

I've already tried gwt-syncproxy (https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/), but I didn't understand how to login to AppEngine. The example given and the library provided does not correspond.

Thanks!
Giovanni.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still working on a more formative tutorial since taking over the GWT-Syncproxy project, so sorry for the confusion. As you noted, the examples on the front page to not correspond to the Android library. Those methods are meant for the java standalone library usage.

In the meantime, Focus on the [Android](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/wiki/Android) wiki for implementation instructions. The [source code](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSPAAppTest) also has an example app implemented for testing purposes, but it gives a relatively simple example of how to use the library. I'll hopefully have a better tutorial up and running by end of the summer or so.

Comment: I took a brief look into your example at [MainActivity.java](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/source/browse/trunk/SPAAppTest/src/com/gdevelop/gwt/syncrpc/spaapptest/MainActivity.java).

How did you get user credentials? That's what I think that is missing, how do I pass my login and password to validate on GAE?

And what this means?

Account account = (Account) data.getExtras().get(
                                                LoginUtils.ACCOUNT_KEY);

Comment: So in the example App's case, it has the library handle getting the user to select a Google account (from the Android Accounts system). The code you mentioned retrieves the user-selected account. This account selector is launched down below in the onResume(): LoginUtils.useAccountSelector(true) and LoginUtils.loginAppEngine(...). Take a look at the LoginUtils source: http://goo.gl/DtCZOn. When null is provided for the account, it calls chooseAccount() which launches an intent to get a user-selected Account. This way, we don't directly handle username/password.